# Parse: Posts with the indication of logged in user liked or not

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform, nosql

I'am making an app backed up with `Parse`. Its a simple app which shares photos and others can like,comment on it. I'am getting confused in designing proper `post` model in `NoSQL` way. i'am considering designing like `Post` contains

Post

- id
- comments
- likes
- like count

Now the problem is how can i indicate the current user liked the post or not? One way is to fetch all the liked posts and do a filtering in client side. That wont be an optimal solution and requires more than one request. How can i handle this scenario efficiently in server side?
Ultimately i want it like

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is with two queries.

Assuming your `Like` class includes a pointer back to the `Post` class, your query logic could be like the following:

- Get `Post` rows for the top 20 sorted by `created_time` descending, default the `user_has_liked` property to false
- Get `Like` rows where `post` matches the above post query and `user` matches the current user
- Update the post rows for any matches found

You can learn about the "matches query" here:

https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#queries-relational

Comment: Is it possible to design in such way that in a single request itself we should get post details with likeCounts, isLikedByUser as we get from Instagram API ?

Comment: You could implement it in a Cloud Function which could return the combined results. This would make it 3 API calls though (1 for cloud, 1 for `Post` query, 1 for `Like` query).

Comment: But in documentation "Cloud functions will be killed after 15 seconds of wall clock time", How can I handle this scenario if we have too many objects?

Comment: Given that you should only be loading a screen full of data at a time, it should never take more than 15 seconds to perform the above.